# Java file data changing

Tags: java, arrays, file, class, dictionary

hope for your help. I need to create a class that searches and changes the Map element (one string) of the another java class. 
it looks like:

```
new Map <String,String>()
.put("time","2015-01-25T03:01:00")
```

I want to compare and replace old date with some random `date.after(now)`. Will be happy even to hear your advices. 
I started with simple changing the data:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

public class FileReplace {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    public void  doIt() {
        try {
            File f1 = new File("TFile.java");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("2015-01-25T03:01:00"))
                    line = line.replace("2015-01-25T03:01:00", "2016-01-06T08:01:00 ");
                lines.add(line);
            }
            fr.close();
            br.close();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(String s : lines)
                 out.write(s);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FileReplace fr = new FileReplace();
        fr.doIt();
    }
}
```

And have some idea how to compare data

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
               Date date1 = sdf;
             //  Date date2 = ;   data from the file

               if (date1.after(date2)) {

          date2 = data2.replace() // some random future data 

               }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to create a new Map and put the value for the key `time`

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("time","2015-01-25T03:01:00");
```

Later you can call the below to change the value corresponding to the key `time`,

```
map.put("time","2016-01-06T10:01:00");
```

Also, If you need date in the above format, you may have to use a `date formatter` to convert date object to string.